# Array from database data in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

How can I make array with values of row in database Sqlite in python?

```
def dropname():
   db = get_db()
   dropname  = db.execute("SELECT name FROM names WHERE ID_dol = 1")
   dropname = cur.fetchall()
   return render_template('form_names.html', dropname=dropname)
```

Answer (score 2):

`fetchall()` returns a list of rows, where each row is a list of column values.

You have to extract the first column value from each row:

```
dropname = [row[0] for row in dropname]
```

Answer (score -1):

problem is that you're not fetching the query in the variable "dropname"

you should replace

```
dropname = cur.fetchall()
return render_template('form_names.html', dropname=dropname)
```

by

```
data = dropname.fetchall()
return render_template('form_names.html', dropname=data)
```

then in your HTML to call it, you do

> {{ dropname[n] }}

where n is the column's index